# Set In enum for C#

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I would like to find a way to check to see if a set of values are contained in my variable.

```
[Flags]
public enum Combinations
{
    Type1CategoryA = 0x01,      // 00000001
    Type1CategoryB = 0x02,      // 00000010
    Type1CategoryC = 0x04,      // 00000100
    Type2CategoryA = 0x08,      // 00001000
    Type2CategoryB = 0x10,      // 00010000
    Type2CategoryC = 0x20,      // 00100000
    Type3 = 0x40                // 01000000
}

bool CheckForCategoryB(byte combinations)
{

    // This is where I am making up syntax

    if (combinations in [Combinations.Type1CategoryB, Combinations.Type2CategoryB])
        return true;
    return false;

    // End made up syntax
}
```

I am a transplant to .NET from Delphi.  This is fairly easy code to write in Delphi, but I am not sure how to do it in C#.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you mean "at least one of the flags":

```
return (combinations
     & (byte)( Combinations.Type1CategoryB | Combinations.Type2CategoryB)) != 0;
```

also - if you declare it as `Combinations combinations` (rather than `byte`), you can drop the `(byte)`

```
bool CheckForCategoryC(Combinations combinations)
{
    return (combinations & (Combinations.Type1CategoryB | Combinations.Type2CategoryB) ) != 0;
}
```

If you mean "exactly one of", I would just use a `switch` or `if` etc.

Comment: If you are going to do this, it would also be a good idea to declare `public enum Combinations : byte`.

Comment: Heh, +1 from me for being quick enough to both get the answer up and get 10 upvotes before i even posted mine :)

Answer (score 1):

For an easier way to "check" those value, you might want to check [Umbrella](http://www.codeplex.com/umbrella) on CodePlex. They built some nice and sweet Extension Methods for verifiing bit flags on enums. Yes it's an abstraction but I think we should focus more on the readability than the implementation itself.

Enjoy.

Answer (score -2):

I think like this, if I understand the question correctly

```
if (combinations == Combinations.Type1CategoryB | Combinations.Type2CategoryB)
```

Comment: That will not work if combination is anything else besides the two possibilities.

assume combinations = Type1CategoryB | Type2CategoryB | Type2CategoryC. Then your check fails, which is not what's wanted.